# solidity remix ethereum msg.sender.balance lavalue rquired aerror cannot deduct balance from msg.sender.address how to deduct balance

Tags: solidity

```
function myFunction (uint _donateAmount) public payable {   
         msg.sender.balance = msg.sender.balance - _donateAmount;
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue.
           msg.sender.balance = msg.sender.balance - _donateAmount;
```

Can anyone suggest me how to deduct balance from msg.sender?
Thank you

---

I want to pass function the value with parameters

```
contract Donation {
     mapping(address=>uint) donation;
  
     **function donate(uint _donateAmount) public payable {
        donation[msg.sender] += _donateAmount;**

     *// How will i deduct the main balance of the account here??
      //  Something msg.sender.balance -= _donateAmount
      //  Once a account donates, a decrease in his main balance be it 
      //  on ganache or Remix id , a decrease in main balance has to be          
      //  immediately reflected . Thank you* 
    }

  

}
```

Comment: With payable modifier, the amount will be subtracted from your balance automatically. More information about payable modifier here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/cheatsheet.html?highlight=payable#modifiers

Comment: I have already attached payable function donate(uint _donateAmount) public payable

Comment: I will be really thankfull if u can give me a code , its my project , i am stuck here for last 2 weeks i am unable to proceed with my frontend as i am stuck on this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A user must to call a function for deposit a specific tokens amount. In this case, you're using wrong logic.

You can see the logic of this smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Donation {

    // Declare a mapping that contain according user address how many tokens user sent to smart contract like 'donation'
    mapping(address=>uint) donation;

    // With 'payable' keyword, I add amount to smart contract balance.
    // And then, I increase value about 'donation' mapping with _donateAmount
    function donate(uint _donateAmount) public payable {
        donation[msg.sender] += _donateAmount;
    }

    // This function allow to see how many tokens user deposited who call this function
    function getBalanaceDonor() external view returns(uint) {
        return donation[msg.sender];
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you're using Remix IDE when call `donate` function, you must put the amount value to donate into `VALUE` textbox found in `DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS` section

Comment: you must put the amount value to donate into VALUE textbox found in DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS Sir I dont want to use VALUE textbox in Remix , because i have to create frontend. Thank you .

Comment: In fact, I said if you must to test it on Remix IDE you must to put value into that textbox. Otherwise, you can pass to function the value with parameters.